# Manage download bandwidth with node

Tags: node.js, nginx, bandwidth

I have a site where people can download large files (ie ISO files). As you can imagine the bandwidth to the server is limited. So I need a solution (preferably using node or Nginx) that can control the bandwidth.

For example imagine 3 users (A, B, C) who respectively want to download files X, Y, and Z.
The Server has a total bandwidth of 10MB/s (for demonstration).
B and C are regular users, A is a premium user. regular users are entitled to 1 MB/s at most (unless the server is maxed, then it's less) and premium Users are entitled to an equal share of the remaining bandwidth.
Which means 10MB/s-1MB/s-1MB/s=8MB/s remaining bandwidth.
Since A is the only current premium user online, he gets the full 8MB/s speed.

Is there a package or solution that would allow me to implement a bandwidth management system like this? Where Bandwidth for file downloads could be regulated using node.js?

[image]

Comment: So if you have 10 regular users the premium users get 0MB/s?

Comment: Didn't think about that, I guess they'd have to share a certain percentage. I will rewrite the post, as the exact implementation is not the issue, but programmatic control of bandwidth

Comment: I'm afraid asking for specific libraries or tools is off topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Its not about libraries its about infrastructure. Also afaik there are no libraries that do this sort of thing

Comment: You're literally asking _"Is there a package or solution that would allow me to implement a bandwidth management system like this"_. That sounds to me like you're asking for a library/package/tool. If you're looking to implement a system like this yourself, your question is too broad.